# Jquery live search on an mvc project

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to execute a live table search using jquery. For some reason I can't get it to work, even a copy-paste from a working tutorial is not working.

Here's my code:

```
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Live search" />

    <table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)             </th>
    <th>    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)           </th>
    <th>    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Amount)         </th>
    <th>    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)          </th>
    <th>    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Catagory.Name)  </th>
    <th>    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Supplier.Name)  </th>
    <th>
</tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)              </td>
    <td>    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)            </td>
    <td>    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)          </td>
    <td>    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)           </td>
    <td>    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Catagory.Name)   </td>
    <td>    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Supplier.Name)   </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
    </td>
</tr>
    }
```

The script:

```
     <script src="jquery-1.10.2">
$("#search").on("keyup", function () {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $("table tr").each(function (index) {
        if (index !== 0) {

            $row = $(this);

            var name = $row.find("td:second").text();

            if (name.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
                $row.hide();
            }
            else {
                $row.show();
            }
        }
    });
});
    </script>
```

I would appreciate any help!
Thanx!

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: No, just no response. I hit the chars inside the input box and nothing.

Comment: I did see an error in the console window, `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: second`. That is what led my to a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your pseudo selector `("td:second")`. Try changing that to `"td:nth-child(2)"`.

Here is the full JS:

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function () {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $("table tr").each(function (index) {
        if (index !== 0) {

            $row = $(this);

            var name = $row.find("td:nth-child(2)").text();

            if (name.indexOf(value) < 0) {
                $row.hide();
            }
            else {
                $row.show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z5K3b/) that removes the MVC portions, and shows it working.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help!
It's not not working, maybe its due to the MVC helpers?

Comment: There were another bug in your JS too. I didn't notice it at first, but your indexOf comparison should be `< 0` not `!== 0`.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. I changed the version in my fiddle and it still worked. Are there any errors in the console when you run?

Comment: No, that's the weird thing. No errors. I'm pretty new with this so I'm asking to see if I'm not making any silly mistake. Copied the code you wrote from the fiddle, still no result.

Comment: Found it.
I was missing <script type="text/javascript">

Thank you!